# Apache redirect on first unsuccessful logon attempt

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

Is it possible to set-up apache to redirect user in case it enters incorrect credentials to a custom page ? We use ldap (AD) as AuthnProvider.

Comment: What scripting language does your website use? It could be easier to do it that way than with Apache.

Comment: I am looking for a way to achieve solely using Apache. Is this possible or there is no way ?